# Jquery AddClass and RemoveClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to addclass and removeclass when I click the tab, when click the tab on the first time, `shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label` add a class call `activetab` , if I click again the tab or click others tab , the class `activetab` will remove. Reason to do this is because i want the active tab have a special css. Any idea how to do this ? AddClass and RemoveClass ... Thanks

```js
$(function () {
    $('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label').click(function () {
  $(this).removeClass("activetab");
  $(this).addClass("activetab");
        $(this).next('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content').slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        return false;
    });
    $('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label').bind('touchstart', function (e) {  
        $(this).trigger('click');
        e.preventDefault();  
    });
});
```

```css
.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_container {
 position:relative;
 clear:both; 
 font-family:'Raleway';
 margin-bottom:10px;
 color:#000;
}
.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_container  li{
 
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style:none;
 color: #888;

 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background: #fff;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label{
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#000;
 padding:10px;
}

.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content {
  display:none;
  font-size:15px;
  text-align:justify;
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
  
}

.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content:last-of-type {

}
.shopiteminfo_mobile_productsdetail_inner_container{
 width:95%;
 border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
 margin-bottom:10px; 
 margin-left:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
.shopiteminfo_mobile_productsdetail_inner_container .shopiteminfo_mobile_label{
 display:list-item;
 list-style:none;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13px;
 padding:3px;
}

.shopiteminfo_mobile_productsdetail_gallery_container{
 padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.shopiteminfo_mobile_productsdetail_gallery_container img{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 
}
.shopiteminfo_mobile_productsdetail_galleryname{
 background:#09c;
 color:#fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:5px;
 width:auto;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_container">
                    <li class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_tobeclick">
                      <label class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label">A</label>
                      <div class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content">
       test
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_tobeclick">
                      <label class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label">B</label>
                      <div class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content">
                        test
                      </div>                    
                    </li>
                    <li class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_tobeclick">
                      <label class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label">C</label>
                      <div class="shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content">
                        test
                      </div>                   
                    </li>
                </div>
```

Comment: [**`jQuery.toggleClass`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/fh6tg75s/2/

```
    $(function () {
    $('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label').click(function () {
       $(this).next('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_content').slideToggle();
$(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
$(this).toggleClass("activetab");
$('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label').not(this).removeClass("activetab");        
        return false;
    });
    $('.shopiteminfo_content_mobile_label').bind('touchstart', function (e) {       
        $(this).trigger('click');
        e.preventDefault();     
    });



});
```

Comment: hi, when click itself still red ? not back to normal ?

Comment: let me change it if you need so.

Answer (score 3):

you should use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(this).toggleClass("activetab");
```

This would remove the css class if its already present or add it if its not.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the below

```
$(this).removeClass("activetab");
$(this).addClass("activetab");
```

to which uses [`$.fn.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(this).toggleClass("activetab");
```

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the state argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a try you can use the ternary operator ***?:*** which also may referred to as ternary if. In just a single line of code check if your element has the active class or not. If it has then on click remove it and if it doesn't have then add this. Here's the code,

***HTML :***

```
<div id="mainDiv">Click Here</div>
```

***CSS :***

```
.activeDiv{
    background-color : green;   
}
```

***jQuery :***

```
$("#mainDiv").on("click", function(){
    $(this).hasClass("activeDiv") ? $(this).removeClass("activeDiv") : $(this).addClass("activeDiv")
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/jx2xh3pm/)

Comment: It's the shortest way I guess answered here already. I just gave an option to dig a ittle bit.